# Redirecting 2 or more similar patterns in .htaccess rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have similar URLs which I want to redirect but the issue is that the first URL overrides the others. For example

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/about about_user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/message/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) message_user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

But the first `RewriteRule` overrides the others so if I have something like this

```
example.com/user/message/myName
example.com/user/myName/about
```

They are all redirected to `user.php`. Please am new to this, how can I get it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have a $ sign after your regular expressions, so it becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/about$ about_user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/message/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ message_user.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```